# Oauth: redirect after Successful Authorization, how?

Tags: oauth

I would like to people to log in on our Wireless Network by their Facebook or Twitter account. So I will use Oauth..

If the user authorized our App succesfully, he must me redirected to a our website. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Twitter (OAuth 1) you do this by supplying an `oauth_callback` parameter in the first request or by specifying a callback URL when registering your application with Twitter.

In OAuth2 (which Facebook uses) the flow is different but the parameter name is `redirect_uri`.

These are your only options.